# UIToolbar with dynamic number of barButtonItems and multiselection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create a UIToolbar that will add it´s buttons from an array. Or perhaps a segmented control.

The problem is that i don´t know before hand how many buttons or segments I need and also if its more than, say 4-5 buttons I want to be able to scroll or similar horizontally for display more buttons.

I want to be able to have multi selection so which approach would be the best to take for this?

A tableViews content will be based on the selection of the buttons on the toolbar. 
Any tips for how I can make this work? or a recommendation for a tutorial out there regarding this would be much welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnAdd = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
    target:self
    action:@selector(AddOperation)] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *btnEdit = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
    target:self
    sction:@selector(EditOperation)] autorelease];

UIToolbar *rightToolBar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 46)] autorelease];
rightToolBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
rightToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:40.0/255.0 green:48.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:0.0];
NSArray *buttonsRight = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnEdit, btnAdd, nil];
[rightToolBar setItems:buttonsRight];
[self.view addSubView:rightToolBar];
```

Comment: Awsome, It works perfectly. Any tips regarding multiselection?

Comment: No dear if i got that then i will surely tell you. And if you really like my answer then accept it and vote up...